# Plugin for having elements "fly" on/off screen when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, plugins

does anyone know of a javascript/jQuery plugin that will "fly" elements onto and out of the screen as I scroll down a page?

To better describe:
I'm picturing a long, vertically scrolling page, where all the content is in little "content boxes", then as a result of different actions (in this case, as a result of scrolling), I want these boxes to be able to fly onto or off the screen.

Maybe this could be described as some kind of cross between jQuery animate and parallax scrolling?

I feel like I've seen that type of effect somewhere before and I just can't remember where...

Comment: I'd suggest you mock something up to show us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go... http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact effect you want but I would use a css class that gets applied/removed to containers depending on the scroll position.

You can animate the change with css transitions.

Answer (score 1):

[WOW.js](https://wowjs.uk/)

> Reveal CSS animation as you scroll down a page. By default, you can
> use it to trigger animate.css animations. But you can easily change
> the settings to your favorite animation library.